# Insert data from text file (saved in my PC) to tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have one problem, I am totally beginner and I would like Insert or convert data, which I have on my PC like txt file to my tables created by Mysql language. Is it possible? 
Table has same columns like txt file.
Thank you so much

Comment: Please give sample data from txt file and which data from txt is you want to insert in which table=>field.

Comment: Please mark as answer my answer below if it has helped you. Otherwise comment on it so we can all improve it and help other people who are facing a similar problem

Comment: Ok for know i receive the file, which is .csv file. This file contains 10 column with text data. I want this file load to my table in my database, but it writing ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/home/filip/Desktop/zkouska.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)

Comment: Post the code you have used so we can see where you are going wrong. Without any code it is a guessing game that won't help either of us. Make sure you use the `code` tag when posting code

Answer (score 1):

You can write direct **sql query** Like this

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C://path/to/yourfilename.txt'

INTO TABLE 'database_name'.'table_name'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'

(column1,column2)

Here i assumed that your fields are terminated by semi column.
for line termination **Character and Escape sequence**  you can take reference from this thread

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple program that loops through the content of the file and inserts the data into the database. Here is [something](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm) to get you started.

This simply inserts the data you have put in the PHP code.

What you will want to do is to open a file and insert the data from it

> > mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
> >     mysql_select_db('db_name') or die(mysql_error());
> >
> > $lines = file('company.txt');
> >     $company_names = "";    $insert_string
> >     = "INSERT INTO `company`(`company_name`) VALUES";  $counter = 0;  $maxsize = count($lines);
>
> foreach($lines as $line => $company)  {
>
> > $insert_string .= "('".$company."')";  $counter++;  if($counter <
> >     $maxsize) {  $insert_string .= ",";  }//if   }//foreach 
> >     mysql_query($insert_string) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I never work with PHP code and I don't know how to do it, I am trying it, but i need some time. Thank you so much. Somebody said me, the problem is in privileges of the user.

Comment: No problem what language are you using to solve the above mentioned problem?